# Is the vector space finite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The vector subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ (polynomials)
>
> $U:=${$f∈\mathbb{R}[X] | f(\alpha+1)-f(\alpha)=f(\beta+1)-f(\beta)                  
> Ɐ\alpha,\beta∈\mathbb{R}$}
>
> is finite-dimensional?

I know that $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is finite-dimensional, because it has a basis {$1,x,x^2,...,x^n$} and its dimension is $\dim(\mathbb{R}[X])=n+1$. So theoretically a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ must be finite too. Is that right? Otherways I don't know how to demonstrate that. Any help please

Comment: $\mathbb R[X]$ is *not* finite dimensional, because the powers of $x$ don't stop at $n$, they keep going forever! As for the question, essentially $U$ consists of all polynomials $f$ such that the polynomial $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$ is a constant. If $g$ is a constant, can you prove that $f$ must be of degree at most one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\mathbb R[X]$ is infinite-dimensional.  A basis is $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots\}$ (there is no $n$ where this stops).  But $U$ is indeed finite-dimensional.

Hint: if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, what is the degree of $f(X+1)-f(X)$?

Comment: Ok, then $f(X+1)-f(X)$ would have a degree $0$. So $U$ is finite-dimensional, but what would be a basis of $U$?